# Sharepoint Pages Library path

Tags: searchserviceapplication, path

I'm working on creating a Sharepoint dev environment, and am working on setting up the search site. I've restored the content database from the main server, and am a bit confused about paths.

I have a page (`domainname/sites/search/Pages/searchpage.aspx`). On the main server, I can access it via a link to `http://domainname/sites/search/searchpage.aspx`; however, the URL `http://testdomainname/sites/search/searchpage.aspx` results in a `Page Not Found` on the test server. (I can still access the page via `testdomainname/sites/search/Pages/searchpage.aspx`

What's the difference, and why does it work on one server, and not another? I'm assuming it has something to do with the search service configuration, since that's the only difference between the two, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue too. In my case it was related between creating a search center as subsite or creating a search center as site collection. In the first scenario it added the /pages/ to the url.